# Slack chatbot connecting to Bubble database

Tags: chatbot, slack, zapier, bubble.io

Is it possible to have a Slack bot that passes information to and from a Bubble app, such that replying to the bot serves as data input for the database, and the bot can retrieve information from the database to answer queries in the Slack channel. Possibly with Zapier?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the info on Slack website about how to build a slack bot: https://api.slack.com/authentication/basics

Knowing Bubble has a database to store and retrieve data AND can receive API calls (webhooks) and call API's it should be possible to use Bubble and Slack to create a functioning Slack Bot.